# How can I ensure that my user goes to a specific path (written in the url) via React-Router-Dom without automatically going to the default home page?

Tags: reactjs, react-router, react-router-dom

I'm currently running into an issue where if a user types in `localhost:3000/resume`, it would default back to `localhost:3000`. It works just fine when I click the button I wrote to specifically navigate to the resume page, but I want it so that if they type in that specific path in the URL they should be able to visit that page without having to start from the landing page and navigating to there. Here is my code that contains the Router

**App.js**

```
import React from 'react';
import './App.css';
import LandingPage from './pages/LandingPage/LandingPage';
import {Route,Router, Redirect} from 'react-router-dom';
import history from './history';
import Projects from './pages/Projects/Projects';
import Experiences from './pages/Experiences/Experiences';
import Resume from './pages/Resume/Resume'

function App() {
  return (
    <div className="App">
      <Router history = {history}>
        <Route path = "/" component = {LandingPage} exact/>
        <Route path = "/projects" component = {Projects} exact/>
        <Route path = "/experiences" component = {Experiences} exact/>
        <Route path = "/resume" component = {Resume} exact/>
        <Redirect to = "/"/>
      </Router>
    </div>
  );
}

export default App;
```

**history.js**

```
import  {createBrowserHistory} from "history";

export default createBrowserHistory()
```

Comment: Why are you redirecting at the end?

Comment: Also, you're missing a Switch and that might be causing all the routes to render including the redirect at the end.

Comment: Yes, the lack of a switch was the cause of the issue. I wanted to put a redirect since I don't want any "phony" URLs to be hit even though it will still route back to the landing page via Redirect. For instance /fakePath will just route to / making it look nicer from the user's URL perspective.  Thank you

Comment: In that case depending on which React Router version you're on, you can have that as a `<Route path="*"><Redirect to="/" /></Route>` to handle all invalid routes.

Comment: Hi Shawn, thanks for replying. Could `<Route path="*"><Redirect to="/" /></Route>` just be condensed to `<Redirect to="/">`? If we use  a Switch, it will pick the first route that matches the location or just go to the first redirect it matches. Perhaps we could also do this  `<Redirect from= "*" to="/">`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks @Shawn_Yap, here's the new `App.js` code in case anyone else has created the same error I did.

You need a switch otherwise it seems to render all routes then redirect back to the landing page. Here's the documentation for further reference. [Switch Documentation React Router Dom](https://reactrouter.com/core/api/Switch)

**App.js**

```
import React from 'react';
import './App.css';
import LandingPage from './pages/LandingPage/LandingPage';
import {Route,Router, Switch,Redirect} from 'react-router-dom';
import history from './history';
import Projects from './pages/Projects/Projects';
import Experiences from './pages/Experiences/Experiences';
import Resume from './pages/Resume/Resume'

function App() {
  return (
    <div className="App">
      <Router history = {history}>
        <Switch>
          <Route path = "/projects" component = {Projects} exact/>
          <Route path = "/experiences" component = {Experiences} exact/>
          <Route path = "/resume" component = {Resume} exact/>
          <Route path = "/" component = {LandingPage} exact/>
          <Redirect from="*" to = "/"/>
        </Switch>
      </Router>
    </div>
  );
}

export default App;
```